# Flex - Placement of Legend for a chart

Tags: apache-flex, charts, legend

I would like to be able to specify the placement of a legend for a linechart.  Currently, it continues to appear to the right of the chart.  I have tried playing with the width/height of the chart to no avail... Putting the legend before the linechart in the mxml causes it to appear to the left.  I can't seem to get it appear at the bottom though.  I can't seem to find any good examples for this.  They don't seem to specify anything but the legend usually shows up below the chart, I can't seem to do it.  Optionally, it would be okay to somehow minimize the legend..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what container are your line chart and legend in?  its sounds like you are using either an HBox or an application with the layout="horizontal".  To move the legend below use either a VBox or application layout of vertical.  Or you can use a canvas and use constraints (left, right, top, bottom) or x and y coordinates

Comment: I missed the last part to minimze.  Your easiest implementation would be to use states and hide and show the legend that way.

Comment: As well as making sure you're using a vertical layout to position the legend control below the chart as Shua suggests, you might also find it useful to set the legend's direction property to "horizontal".

You might also need to set the legend control's width property to something like "100%" to make sure it fills your new vertical layout.